# User logout after closing tab in React app

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, onbeforeunload

I have project in React. I use keykloak for authorization. I try to implement simple mechanism of logout when user close tab. I have code like below:

```
class App extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
    constructor(props : IProps){
        super(props);
        this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak })
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
       window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnmount);
    }
    
    onUnmount = () => {
       keycloak.logout();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnmount);
    }
```

It dosen't work at all. I don't know why. When I close the tab and open again I'm still logged in.
Why it dosen't work?

Comment: Why not just remove the entire key from localstorage?

Comment: When I delete localstorage manually then user is still logged in

Comment: You need to call logout endpoint of used IDP, otherwise there will be still valid user IDP session. Check doc of used library - it is really not clear what  is that `keycloak` object. Many different OIDC libs with different features can be behind that object.

Comment: I have also button for logout in app which uses this method and logout user properly.

Comment: I know why it dosen't work. The answer is in doc: "For other browser applications, you can redirect the browser to http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri, which logs you out if you have an SSO session with your browser."

Comment: @KrzysztofMichalski Did you find any working solution to handle your usecase. Even I am  under same situations and tried all possible ways of redirecting user to keycloak's logout URL, keycloak.logout(), navigator.sendBeacon to logout current user's session via keycloak's admin rest api etc. Nothing worked for me yet.